# Order database rows by location

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i'm building a website that contains a database of places, and in the MySQL database i have stored the latitude and longitude of a certain place. When loaded, I then calculate the distance between the user (user's location is aquired via HTML5 Geolocation) and the stored location using either the haversine formula or google maps api's DistanceMatrix.

What I want is to order the output from the closest to the farthest location. Is that possible using a mysql query, or i can only do it with javascript?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly possible - although I'm not sure that there's much wrong with a js solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the SQL query, you can create a new column that uses your formula to calculate the distance between the user and specific location. Then you want to use the [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) keyword and choose the distance column to sort by ASC (already default). I hope this helps!

Comment: I just realized that @rjdown provided a link to what I pretty much said.